# AWS Serverless lambda times out while connecting to redshift

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-architecture

I am getting constant timeout while connecting from AWS lambda to redshift.

I get Timeout exception from my python code

I have already added the vpc section:

```
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-xxxxxxx
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-xxxxxxx
```

So whats happenign here?

Answer (score 4):

To troubleshoot this issue, you can use following steps;

1. Use [VPC Reachability Analyzer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-insights-analyzes-reachability-and-visibility-in-vpcs/) : Create and analyze path with Source type Network Interfaces and Source as Network Interface Id of the your AWS Lambda. Furthermore, select Destination type as Network Interfaces and Destination as network Interface Id of the AWS Red Shift. Put Destination port as 5439 or the communication port you are using, keep Protocol as TCP.

*Note*: It takes few minutes for completion of this path analysis.*

OR

2. If you have enabled [VPC Flow Logs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/), then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, which AWS resource is rejecting the network traffic.

*Note: It takes few minutes to load vpc network flow logs in aws cloudwatch*